# Can malloc cause a crash when detouring a function in C++ to copy a data string from ExtTextOut in a target process?

Tags: c++, hook, detours

I am trying to make a detour using MSDN Detours 3.0 to register text drawn by **ExtTextOut()** from a third party software. I have created a DLL which I inject in the target software. When I detour ExtTextOut I try to copy the string sent to the method and read the text to a textfile in modified format. Since the input string is UTF-16 and I am only interested in keeping the ASCII characters lower than 127 I have made some logic for this.

The problem is, though, that my program crashes a while after it is injected in the target. I suspect that it might have something to do with the **malloc function**.

If I use malloc to locate memory in a process, **can I guaratee that this will not override any memory in the target process?** If that would be the case, how can I create a function to make sure that my malloc wont interfere with the target process.

The code:

```
BOOL WINAPI Mine_ExtTextOut(HDC hdc, int X, int Y, UINT options, RECT* lprc, LPCWSTR text, UINT cbCount, INT* lpSpacingValues)
{

    // 
    if(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(text)[0] == '>'){ 

        //wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>,wchar_t> convert;
        //string utf8_string = convert.to_bytes(text);
        //int n = utf8_string.length();

        int n = cbCount;

        char *buffer = (char*) malloc (n+1);
        char *bufferCopy = (char*) malloc (n+1);

        for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
            if((long) text[i] > 127){
                buffer[i] = ' ';
                continue;
            }
            buffer[i]= (char) text[i];
        }
        buffer[n]='\0';



        bool wasBlank = false;
        int ix = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<n; ++i){
            if(buffer[i] == ' '){
                if(wasBlank || i < 2) continue;
                bufferCopy[ix++] = buffer[i];
                wasBlank = true;
                continue;
            }
            wasBlank = false;
            if(buffer[i] == '>') continue;
            bufferCopy[ix++] = buffer[i];
        }
        bufferCopy[ix]='\0';

        ofstream myFile;
        myFile.open("C:\\temp\\textHooking\\textHook\\example2.txt", ios::app);
        if(buffer[0] == '>'){
            //myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(text), cbCount*sizeof(*text));
            myFile.write(bufferCopy, ix*sizeof(*bufferCopy));
            myFile << endl;
        }

        free(buffer);
        free(bufferCopy);

    }
    BOOL rv = Real_ExtTextOut(hdc, X, Y, options, lprc, text, cbCount, lpSpacingValues);
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: Try closing myfile and before writing checking the fail-flag.

Comment: Good that you saw that but unfortunately that does not solve the problem. Actaully If I comment away almost everything except from malloc down to the orignial call. It still crashes. However, if I comment away everything and only redirects this function to the orignial it works of course.

Comment: What crash info do you get when it does?

Comment: The target software just freezes and windows says that the program has crashed. Somehow it seems that the allocated memory somehow overrides memory already in the process since if I comment out all code except the malloc, it still crashes.

Comment: It's been many years since I worked in the MS C++ world, but I remember similar situations where `free` would get confused about what heap to use.  One possibility is to give up on using the heap and try `alloca`.  (Assuming the number of characters is relatively low.)

Comment: @steven: I'm thinking the same ... having two copies of the c-runtime library (in the calling process and the DLL).  instead of malloc(n+1) try  buffer= GlobalAlloc(GPTR, n+1);

Comment: I tested comment away one of the malloc but the problem remains. I havent been able to test yet the GlobalAlloc() since that does not yield a pointer to char. But anyway, we can say that at least the problem is not caused by multiple c-runtime library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cbCount` parameter of `ExtTextOut()` is expressed in **characters**, but the input parameter of `malloc()` is expressed in **bytes**.  You are hooking the Unicode version of `ExtTextOut()` (aka `ExtTextOutW()`), where `sizeof(WCHAR)` is 2 bytes. You are trying to treat the input string as Ansi, which it is not, and you are not taking UTF-16 surrogates into account.

To do what you are attempting, you need to actually decode the UTF-16 data into Unicode codepoints first before deciding which ones to keep, eg:

```
BOOL WINAPI Mine_ExtTextOut(HDC hdc, int X, int Y, UINT options, RECT* lprc, LPCWSTR text, UINT cbCount, INT* lpSpacingValues)
{
    if ((cbCount > 0) && (text != NULL) && (text[0] == L'>'))
    { 
        // worse case, every UTF-16 character is ASCII and will be kept,
        // so allocate enough memory for at least that many characters
        std::string buffer(cbCount);
        std::string bufferCopy(cbCount);

        int ix1 = 0;
        for (UINT i = 0; i < cbCount;)
        {
            ULONG c;

            // is it a UTF-16 high surrogate?
            if ((text[i] >= 0xD800) && (text[i] <= 0xDBFF))
            {
                // is it at the end of the string?
                if ((i+1) == cbCount)
                {
                    // malformed surrogate
                    break;
                }

                // is it followed by a UTF-16 low surrogate?
                if ((text[i+1] < 0xDC00) || (text[i+1] > 0xDFFF))
                {
                    // malformed surrogate
                    break;
                }

                // decode the surrogate and skip past it
                c = ((ULONG(text[i] - 0xD800) << 10) | ULONG(text[i+1] - 0xDC00)) + 0x10000;
                i += 2;
            }

            // is it a UTF-16 low surrogate?
            else if (text[i] >= 0xDC00) && (text[i] <= 0xDFFF))
            {
                // malformed surrogate
                break;
            }

            // must be a non-surrogated character
            else
            {
                c = (ULONG) text[i];
                ++i;
            }

            // keep it?
            if( c > 127 )
                buffer[ix1] = ' ';
            else
                buffer[ix1] = (char) c;

            ++ix1;
        }

        bool wasBlank = false;
        int ix2 = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < ix1; ++i)
        {
            if (buffer[i] == ' ')
            {
                if (wasBlank || (i < 2)) continue;
                bufferCopy[ix2++] = buffer[i];
                wasBlank = true;
                continue;
            }
            wasBlank = false;
            if (buffer[i] == '>') continue;
            bufferCopy[ix2++] = buffer[i];
        }

        ofstream myFile;
        myFile.open("C:\\temp\\textHooking\\textHook\\example2.txt", ios::app);
        if (myFile)
        {
            myFile.write(bufferCopy.c_str(), ix2);
            myFile << endl;
        }
    }

    return Real_ExtTextOut(hdc, X, Y, options, lprc, text, cbCount, lpSpacingValues);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for really good input. I will definetily test that. Two questions though, why do you break the for-loop if you find a malformed surrogate? Isnt there any chance that the following characters after that might be useful? Also, the statement if((i+1) == n), I guess that n = cbCount?

Comment: OK, now I know for sure that there is something very strange going on. If I just comment out everything except from some the allocation of memory for the string, i:e std::string(cbCount, ' ') the target program crashes. However, if I also comment the allocation out the program runs smoothely. I suspect that the target program might have some tools for preventing DLL-injection. What do you think? But, the strange part is that I can still Detour the function and make some small things in it and add two numbers and the program wont crash. Is there any DLL-injection method that checks the memory?

Comment: A surrogate pair must comprise of valid high and low values. If you encounter a malformed surrogate pair, the text data is corrupt, and you can't really interpret it correctly. If you want, you can skip the malformed surrogate and keep processing the rest of the text, but you are likely to get bad results. And yes, `n` was supposed to be `cbCount`.

Comment: You might be running into conflicting memory managers, since your code is compiled against a different RTL then the target app is.  If you encounter problems allocating memory inside of a detoured function, try switching to `LocalAlloc()` and `LocalFree()` (not `malloc()` or `free()`), or at least wrap them in a custom allocator that you can pass to `std::string`. The idea being that the OS, not the RTL, is allocating/freeing the memory.

Comment: The bytes/wchar_t issue is likely the root problem.  Competing allocators might also be an issue.  I believe the surrogates are a red herring since the user cares about only the ASCII-compatible values and so they can just be skipped like any other high value.  A potential issue is that the values might not be characters but font indexes (if the ETO_GLYPH_INDEX flag is set in the options).  I don't know if fonts generally align indexes with ASCII values for characters in that range.

Comment: Okey, so I tried all of your suggestions now. If I just comment everything out and just allocate memory using LocalAlloc and LocalFree the program does not crash. However, if I put some parts where I actually tries to acess memory the program crashes. There must be something with competing memory managers? Also, I wonder how the DLL injection really works. As I understand a DLL-injector creates a remoteThread in the target process and allocates memory using VirtualAlloc(). Memory that allocated in my function, is that memory allocated in that space or do I have a fundamental misunderstanding?

Comment: Accessing existing memory has no conflict as long as the accessing code is running in the same process that allocated the memory being accessed (unless you use `ReadProcessMemory()`). Differences in memory managers only really comes into play when allocating and freeing memory. If your code is still crashing, please update your question with your latest code, as you are still doing something wrong with it. And if you can, please also show the code that is injecting the DLL and installing the detour.

Comment: Actually I found out the problem which is so silly now when I know what the problem was. It has nothing to do with different real time libraries. Rather its a stupid mistake at the top.
reinterpret_cast<const char*>(text)[0] == '>' - Now what if text[0] == NULL    && cbCount = 0 ?? Yes it will crash.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments here are a few things you could do to try to narrow this down:

Replace malloc: Instead use `buffer= (char *)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, n+1);` and `GlobalFree(buffer)`.  This would make sure it's not a problem with having multiple c-runtime libraries.

Alternately, to make sure there are no situations where you run over the bounds of the allocated buffers, try to malloc a lot more, e.g. `buffer= malloc(n+1024);` and see if that fixes the problem.  If that does, you'll need to comb through your code if you go beyond the valid offsets in the buffers.

A similar approach (for testing) would be to use stack versions of the buffer that are longer than the input you expect, e.g. `char buffer[1024];` and use them like the malloc buffers (of course don't free them) and see what difference this makes.